# How to define method with self-referencing Type return value

Tags: java, generics

Imagine you have the following interface:

```
public interface Selfreferencing<T extends Selfreferencing<T, C>, C extends Comparable<C>> {

}
```

and the following Util class:

```
public class SelfreferencingUtil {
    public static <T,C> Selfreferencing<T, C> selfreferencingUtil(List<T> input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do you define the selfreferencingUtil method types to return an Object of type

```
Selfreferencing<T, C>
```

The above code does not compile with the message:

```
type argument T is not within bounds of type-variable T
```

Comment: public class SelfreferencingUtil<T,C> {

Comment: in most cases this recursive bound is unnecessary

Comment: That may be the case but i am not allowed to change bound here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type variables of the static method must have the same type bounds as the type bounds of `Selfreferencing`:

```
class SelfreferencingUtil {
    public static <T extends Selfreferencing<T, C>,C extends Comparable<C>> Selfreferencing<T, C> selfreferencingUtil(List<T> input) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the purpose of the method, the better return type might be `T`.